# javascript - make setTimeout faster?

Tags: javascript

My code is:

```
function slide(x) 
{
    if (x==undefined)
      var x = 1;
    if (x >= 4096) 
      return;

    document.getElementById("slide").style.backgroundPosition = x + "px 0px";
    x++;
    setTimeout(function() {
        slide(x);
    }, 1);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tatrwkmh/3/)

It makes a spin (?) by changing backgroundPosition, and it works. But it's too slow, I'd want to make it faster, and then gradually slow down. How can I do that?

Comment: Clicking on the button in the Fiddle doesn't do anything for me

Comment: Make your steps bigger. For example, x = x + 5 instead of x++

Comment: I updated jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have rewrite all the function:

```
  function slide() {
    var x = 1;
    var y = 30;
    var clr = setInterval(function(){
      if(x >= 4096) x = 1;
      document.getElementById("slide").style.backgroundPosition = x+"px 0px";
      x+=y;
      y-=0.1;
      if (y<=0) { clearInterval(clr); }
    },10);

  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tatrwkmh/4/

Answer (score 2):

You should pick a higher delay than 1ms. In most browsers 10 to 50 ms would be a lot more reliable. To speed up your animation though, increase `x` increments. For example:

```
function slide(x) 
{
    if(x==undefined) var x = 1;
    if(x >= 4096) return;
    document.getElementById("slide").style.backgroundPosition = x+"px 0px";
    x += 10; // or some other value
    setTimeout(function() {
        slide(x);
    }, 50); // or some other value
}
```

Also, you probably want to check `x` like this:
`if (typeof x === 'undefined') { x = 1; }`, no need for `var`.

**2018 UPDATE**:
Check out the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame API. Using this over a fixed update interval is usually preferable.

Comment: 50ms makes the animation look choppy.  50ms is only 20 frames per second, the human eye doesn't really start to see things as "moving" until about 26.

Comment: That worked, thanks. And how can I make it slowing at the end?

Comment: @zqk check Baro's answer.

Comment: @zqk, try to use an animation library such as GSAP's [TweenLite](https://greensock.com/tweenlite)/[TweenMax](https://greensock.com/tweenmax) or [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Currently the position is being changed by 1 pixel every time `slide` is called, via the line `x++;`. You can make it faster by changing this from `x++` to `x += 2` or `x += 3` etc.

Your animation may look clunky without some sort of easing function, though. You should look into using some sort of animation library instead.

Answer (score 1):

I got it nicely starting fast and then going slower by adding to your code the following:

```
if(x < 1000)
    x+=2
else if(x < 1500)
    x+=1.5
else
    x++;
```